# How to create a customized logout URL in BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress

Does anyone know how to override the BuddyPress logout URL with a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s the same as the regular WordPress logout URL. So you can use the same filter: `'logout_url'`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'wpse_56866_logout_url' );
function wpse_56866_logout_url() 
{
    // set your URL here
    return 'http://example.com';
}
```

Comment: Awesome @toscho -- that was the solution. I greatly appreciate your answer!